# Can I communicate send data from raspberry to other raspberry pi with ROS

Tags: raspberrypi, ros-kinetic, turtlebot3, rasbperrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can I communicate send data from raspberry to other raspberry pi with ROS?
my project is on turtlebot which is tracking object with raspicam and then followed the problem is i use 2 raspi camera so i uses 2 raspberry pi, can i communicate raspi with other raspi ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/310192/can-i-communicate-send-data-from-raspberry-to-other-raspberry-pi-with-ros/) by [Ilhamasy](https://answers.ros.org/users/38316/ilhamasy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2018-12-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes; you can use ROS over a network (WiFi or Ethernet).

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2018-12-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-12-07**:
also, check out http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup for more details.

**Comment by [Ilhamasy](https://answers.ros.org/users/38316/ilhamasy/) on 2018-12-07**:
thanks a lot :)